# Trying to add a image to a GUI but keep getting the error "javac" not found

Tags: java, image, user-interface

I am trying to add an image to my gui but I keep getting the error command "javac" not found

here is the code

```
ImageIcon ISpyImage = new ImageIcon("ISpyPicture.JPG");
panel.add(ISpyImage);
```

I saved the image in the same folder as the program.

Comment: That's possibly because you didn't set up correctly the "path" variable on your Windows machine

Comment: Type just `javac` on the command line and you'll get the same error message.  You must add JRE's location (%JAVA_HOME%\bin) to your PATH environmental variable.

Comment: Give a fast Google search on "setting the Windows path variable for java". BTW an IDE would save you this time.

Comment: `for someone who knows very little about computers how do I go about setting up the "path" correctly` - how about reading some tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

That message has nothing to do with your code.  It appears there is no path to your Java compiler.

Comment: for someone who knows very little about computers how do I go about setting up the "path" correctly....  I just got a new computer with Windows 8 which is not helping me any

Comment: The first step is to install the Java Development Kit.  Those can be found at http://java.sun.com/javase , if I recall correctly.  Once you've installed it, you should have a path to `javac`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed the JDK properly.

See the Java tutorial on [Getting Started with JAVA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) to see what you might be doing wrong. The section on "Common Problems" might help you out.